# Is there any roofed accommodation in Boquillas del Carmen, Mexico?

Tags: accommodation, mexico

Is there any roofed accommodation in [Boquillas del Carmen, Coahuila, Mexico](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boquillas_del_Carmen)?

Background:
We're planning a winter trip to Big Bend National Park but we're not too sure about camping with the cold winter nights where temperatures below freezing are likely and below -5°C are possible (record low is -19°C).  Roofed accommodation in the park is sold out for the period we're looking at.  Roofed accommodation outside the park in the US means 2+ hours of extra driving each day, depending on the destination.

Just across the border from Rio Grande Village is [Boquillas del Carmen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boquillas_del_Carmen), accessible since the [border crossing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boquillas_Port_of_Entry) reopened in 2013.  Is there any roofed accommodation here?  Wikipedia mentions the Buzzards Roost was popular until the border was closed in 2002.  [According to this blog post](http://www.footloosescot.com/mexico-boquillas-crossing-reopens/), it is "being converted into a motel".  What is the situation for winter 2014/2015?

Comment: I have to admit, I read the title and thought "oh my god, no roofs?"

Comment: Roofed as opposed to pitching a tent.  Although my tent has a roof too.

Comment: Literally, no roof on the Buzzards Roost - [The Buzzards Roost is now a shell and had its roof blown off in a windstorm!](http://www.mysanantonio.com/news/local_news/article/Mexican-town-gets-new-life-4432442.php)

Comment: Your link sounds more promising though.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is:

> There are several places to stay in Boquillas.  Most of us ended up in
>   La Zappolita – the former Buzzard’s Roost.  Several private rooms,
>   clean bathrooms, no electricity, and your $25 fee for the night
>   includes a huge breakfast with home-made beans and rice, tortillas,
>   and tamales.

http://terlinguamusic.com/boquillas-overnight-dancing-in-the-dark/

Comment: Gah, as per my comment above, when I researched, Buzzard's Roost had had its roof blown off and wasn't usable.  Looks like they sold and upgraded. Good find!